# Convert Strings distance to double in Google map directions

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

Hello i would like to ask if its possible that the convert the Strings Distance by giving the google map directions and I will convert it to decimal point?

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    Log.e("DISTANCEHECKER", "" + df.format("29 m"));
```

the 29 will change its depends in google direction result maybe it will change as Km or M it depends. I need to get the exact decimal for this.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You can use Double.parseDouble() to convert a String to a double.
What kind of output do you expect if the input is "29 m" and what if it is "29 km"

Comment: yes its random number so there is possible way that meters , km and miles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. its a working Code. To Format Your String Distance to any type of unit .....

```
 try{
        String distance = "29.336 m"; //Notice that one space between digit and unit.
        String arr_distance = distance.split(" "); //split on space
        Double digit_distance =Double.parseDouble(arr_distance [0]); // First element as a double to digit.
        String unit_distance = arr_distance[1]; // Second Element as String to unit
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.println(digit_distance);
        switch(unit_distance){
              case "m":
                  System.out.println("DISTANCEHECKER" + df.format(digit_distance));
                  break;
              case "km":   
                  System.out.println("DISTANCEHECKER" + df.format(digit_distance*1000));
                  break;
             ............
             ................  //more Code Omitted.as per your requirement
     }
     }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Please format your code and don't use quote blocks for normal text

Comment: How about the Mi ? its miles what it will be format? @Vikrant